# Makefile and run on Mac M1 chip?

Tags: macos, makefile, g++, apple-silicon

Is there any way to compile and run this on Mac M1 chip? I have xcode installed and all other c and c++ libraries. I try with UTM/ubunto also dodnt work.

```
default:
    g++ -O3 -c oldbloom/bloom.cpp -o oldbloom.o
    g++ -O3 -c bloom/bloom.cpp -o bloom.o
#   g++ -O3 -c sha256/sha256.c -o sha256.o
    gcc -O3 -c base58/base58.c -o base58.o
    gcc -O3 -c rmd160/rmd160.c -o rmd160.o
    g++ -O3 -c sha3/sha3.c -o sha3.o
    g++ -O3 -c sha3/keccak.c -o keccak.o
    gcc -O3 -c xxhash/xxhash.c -o xxhash.o
    g++ -O3 -c util.c -o util.o
    g++ -m64 -mssse3 -Wno-unused-result -Wno-write-strings -O2 -c secp256k1/Int.cpp -o Int.o
    g++ -m64 -mssse3 -Wno-unused-result -Wno-write-strings -O2 -c secp256k1/Point.cpp -o Point.o
    g++ -m64 -mssse3 -Wno-unused-result -Wno-write-strings -O2 -c secp256k1/SECP256K1.cpp -o SECP256K1.o
    g++ -m64 -mssse3 -Wno-unused-result -Wno-write-strings -O2 -c secp256k1/IntMod.cpp -o IntMod.o
    g++ -m64 -mssse3 -Wno-unused-result -Wno-write-strings -O2 -c secp256k1/Random.cpp -o Random.o
    g++ -m64 -mssse3 -Wno-unused-result -Wno-write-strings -O2 -c secp256k1/IntGroup.cpp -o IntGroup.o
    g++ -m64 -mssse3 -Wno-write-strings -O2 -o hash/ripemd160.o -c hash/ripemd160.cpp
    g++ -m64 -mssse3 -Wno-write-strings -O2 -o hash/sha256.o -c hash/sha256.cpp
    g++ -m64 -mssse3 -Wno-write-strings -O2 -o hash/ripemd160_sse.o -c hash/ripemd160_sse.cpp
    g++ -m64 -mssse3 -Wno-write-strings -O2 -o hash/sha256_sse.o -c hash/sha256_sse.cpp
    g++ -o keyhunt keyhunt.cpp base58.o rmd160.o  hash/ripemd160.o hash/ripemd160_sse.o hash/sha256.o hash/sha256_sse.o bloom.o oldbloom.o xxhash.o util.o Int.o  Point.o SECP256K1.o  IntMod.o  Random.o IntGroup.o sha3.o keccak.o  -lm -lpthread
    rm -r *.o
clean:
    rm keyhunt
```

I get all this errors when i try to compile it on Mac M1:

```
In file included from secp256k1/Int.cpp:18:
secp256k1/Int.h:204:27: error: invalid output constraint '=d' in asm
  __asm__( "mulq  %[b];" :"=d"(rhi),"=a"(rlo) :"1"(a),[b]"rm"(b));
                          ^
secp256k1/Int.h:211:43: error: invalid output constraint '=D' in asm
  __asm__ ("movq %1,%0;shrdq %3,%2,%0;" : "=D"(c) : "r"(a),"r"(b),"c"(n));
                                          ^
secp256k1/Int.h:218:43: error: invalid output constraint '=D' in asm
  __asm__ ("movq %1,%0;shldq %3,%2,%0;" : "=D"(c) : "r"(b),"r"(a),"c"(n));
                                          ^
secp256k1/Int.h:234:7: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_addcarryx_u64'
  c = _addcarry_u64(c, _umul128(x[1], y, &h), carry, dst + 1); carry = h;
      ^
secp256k1/Int.h:223:32: note: expanded from macro '_addcarry_u64'
#define _addcarry_u64(a,b,c,d) __builtin_ia32_addcarryx_u64(a,b,c,(long long unsigned int*)d);
                               ^
secp256k1/Int.h:235:7: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_addcarryx_u64'
  c = _addcarry_u64(c, _umul128(x[2], y, &h), carry, dst + 2); carry = h;
      ^
secp256k1/Int.h:223:32: note: expanded from macro '_addcarry_u64'
#define _addcarry_u64(a,b,c,d) __builtin_ia32_addcarryx_u64(a,b,c,(long long unsigned int*)d);
                               ^
secp256k1/Int.h:236:7: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_addcarryx_u64'
  c = _addcarry_u64(c, _umul128(x[3], y, &h), carry, dst + 3); carry = h;
      ^
secp256k1/Int.h:223:32: note: expanded from macro '_addcarry_u64'
#define _addcarry_u64(a,b,c,d) __builtin_ia32_addcarryx_u64(a,b,c,(long long unsigned int*)d);
                               ^
secp256k1/Int.h:237:7: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_addcarryx_u64'
  c = _addcarry_u64(c, _umul128(x[4], y, &h), carry, dst + 4); carry = h;
      ^
secp256k1/Int.h:223:32: note: expanded from macro '_addcarry_u64'
#define _addcarry_u64(a,b,c,d) __builtin_ia32_addcarryx_u64(a,b,c,(long long unsigned int*)d);
                               ^
secp256k1/Int.h:253:7: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_addcarryx_u64'
  c = _addcarry_u64(c, _umul128(x[1], y, &h), carry, dst + 1); carry = h;
      ^
secp256k1/Int.h:223:32: note: expanded from macro '_addcarry_u64'
#define _addcarry_u64(a,b,c,d) __builtin_ia32_addcarryx_u64(a,b,c,(long long unsigned int*)d);
                               ^
secp256k1/Int.h:254:7: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_addcarryx_u64'
  c = _addcarry_u64(c, _umul128(x[2], y, &h), carry, dst + 2); carry = h;
      ^
secp256k1/Int.h:223:32: note: expanded from macro '_addcarry_u64'
#define _addcarry_u64(a,b,c,d) __builtin_ia32_addcarryx_u64(a,b,c,(long long unsigned int*)d);
                               ^
secp256k1/Int.h:255:7: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_addcarryx_u64'
  c = _addcarry_u64(c, _umul128(x[3], y, &h), carry, dst + 3); carry = h;
      ^
secp256k1/Int.h:223:32: note: expanded from macro '_addcarry_u64'
#define _addcarry_u64(a,b,c,d) __builtin_ia32_addcarryx_u64(a,b,c,(long long unsigned int*)d);
                               ^
secp256k1/Int.h:262:3: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_addcarryx_u64'
  _addcarry_u64(c, 0ULL, carry, dst + (NB64BLOCK - 1));
  ^
secp256k1/Int.h:223:32: note: expanded from macro '_addcarry_u64'
#define _addcarry_u64(a,b,c,d) __builtin_ia32_addcarryx_u64(a,b,c,(long long unsigned int*)d);
                               ^
In file included from secp256k1/Int.cpp:24:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/emmintrin.h:14:2: error: "This header is only meant to be used on x86 and x64 architecture"
#error "This header is only meant to be used on x86 and x64 architecture"
 ^
In file included from secp256k1/Int.cpp:24:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/emmintrin.h:17:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/xmmintrin.h:14:2: error: "This header is only meant to be used on x86 and x64 architecture"
#error "This header is only meant to be used on x86 and x64 architecture"
 ^
In file included from secp256k1/Int.cpp:24:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/emmintrin.h:17:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/xmmintrin.h:17:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:14:2: error: "This header is only meant to be used on x86 and x64 architecture"
#error "This header is only meant to be used on x86 and x64 architecture"
 ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:37:5: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_emms'; did you mean '__builtin_isless'?
    __builtin_ia32_emms();
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:37:5: note: '__builtin_isless' declared here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:37:25: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 2, have 0
    __builtin_ia32_emms();
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:54:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si(__i, 0);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:71:12: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v2si'
    return __builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v2si((__v2si)__m, 0);
           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:133:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_packsswb'
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packsswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
                  ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
```

My question is, is it needed to change Makefile only or the whole script, to work on M1 chip?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "_didn't work_" is not a problem description we can help with.

Comment: Please post any error msg?

Comment: The sources contain inline assembly, and that seems to be in a different dialect than than the compiler you are using wants.  Use of inline assembly makes it unlikely that this program will work unmodified on a different CPU (family) than it was written for, which appears from the compile options to have been Intel x86-64.  There may be a way to build it for M1, but if so, that's not evident from the information presented.